# Import fbx animation - character and rigs seperate when imported

Tags: .fbx

My problem is, when i import an fbx animation, the 3d model and rigs was imported separately.The animation i downloaded was from mixamo, i tried importing it in blender and the character and rigs was separate. But in other laptop it was just fine, and the animation is working